# Relay if powered with ac supply then turns adjacent circuit on automatically

Tags: voltage, relay, ground

I took the idea from the below link to build my own relay board.

http://www.electronics-lab.com/project/toggle-on-off-switch/

[image]

[image]
I connected 3 of this in parallel with voltage. All seems well until I dont power common of relay. If I give AC power to the common of relay the adjacent circuits turns on automatically. The strangest thing is when I push A's button then circuit B & C are affected randomly

Any guess what could be wrong....

Comment: Can you add the schematic for your board?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I noticed: This board has absolutely no capacitor on the supply side (between 5V and GND). This will cause a voltage drop on 5V as soon as one relay is switching.

You need to add a big (like 100uF) capacitor between 5V and GND.